# VBA: Cells Starting with "=" Causing Problems in my Move Macro

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I currently have some code that finds cells not in the first column and moves them over. I'm facing a problem with cells that start with "=". Can you guys think of any work-arounds to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

```
Sub Move()

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim wk As Worksheet

Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng = wk.UsedRange

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value <> "" And cel.Column <> 1 Then
         wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = cel.Value
         cel.Value = ""
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: By "starting with =" do you mean the cells have formulas?  If Yes do you want to move the formulas, or just the values?

Comment: `I'm facing a problem` is not a good explanation. Please explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: They aren't formulas. Basically it is an imported SQL Query and I want to move it all to the first column to analyze it.

Comment: @GSerg The macro stops running at the line with the "=" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either every time in your For each loop

```
If Cstr(cel.Value) <> "" And ... 'you need to do that for every cel.Value occurencies
```

Or declare a variable at the beginning

```
Dim StringInCell as String
For Each cel In rng
StringInCell=Cstr(cel.Value)
    If StringInCell...
```

You may try .Text property as well (though I haven't had luck using that ever, I rather to use CStr). 
This may work as well if the parsed data is throwing an error exception or something:

```
...
wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = Cstr(cel.Value) 'related to the option chosen from above
```

Comment: I get a compile error: Expected: Identifier when using the first solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Casting `Value` to `String` does not do anything in this context.

Comment: @GSerg It does if it's a formula and has error on it, it would parse as "Error". If in the other hand it's a text it should parse as such. Though, you may be right, I'll update my answer again.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're suggesting. The following doesn't seem to work.

Sub Move()

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim wk As Worksheet

Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng = wk.UsedRange

For Each cel In rng
    If Cstr(cel.Value) <> "" And cel.Column <> 1 Then
         wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = Cstr(cel.Value)
         Cstr(cel.Value) = ""
    End If
Next cel
End Sub

Comment: @Rob Remove any use of `CStr`, it's not needed. What is needed is the `wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1).NumberFormat = "@"`, use that before copying the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Move()

    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
    Dim wk As Worksheet

    Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = wk.UsedRange

    For Each cel In rng

        If cel.HasFormula Then
            wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1).Formula = cel.Formula
            cel.ClearContents
        Else
            If cel.Value <> "" And cel.Column <> 1 Then
                With wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1)
                    .NumberFormat = "@" '<<edit: added formatting
                    .Value = cel.Value
                End with
                cel.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error" with the following highlighted.

wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = cel.Value

Comment: Do any of these cells contain errors?  Do you have any merged cells ?

Comment: @Tim Williams your code works fine for me. Results in movement of last column of the used range to Column A.

Comment: The issue is that `cel.Value` contains text that starts with `=` but is not seen as a formula by Excel (so `cel.HasFormula` is `false`). When that text is assigned to `wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1)` Excel tries to evaluate it as a formula because it sees the `=` - it arguably should not, but it's trying to be helpful. The solution is to assign text format to `wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1)` before setting its value, or to prepend a `'`.

Comment: @GSerg - yes - forgot to add that piece after focussing on Formulas ;-/

Answer (score 0):

If you have cells that begin with **=**, but are not to be treated as formulas, but rather as *Text*, then using ***Sgdva***'s alternative suggestion:

```
Sub Move()

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim wk As Worksheet

Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng = wk.UsedRange

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Text <> "" And cel.Column <> 1 Then
         wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = cel.Text
         cel.Value = ""
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version should "de-formularise" a cell before moving it to column **1**:

```
Sub Move2()
    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
    Dim wk As Worksheet, s As String

    Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = wk.UsedRange

    For Each cel In rng
        s = cel.Text
        If s <> "" And cel.Column <> 1 Then
             wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1).Value = s
             cel.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: If there is a problem with `=`, it has to be on setting the value, not on reading it. When the cell contains text starting with `=` that is not treated as a formula, `.Value` returns that text unchanged without trying to evaluate it, so no point in reading `.Text`. But when that text is then assigned to another cell's `.Value`, it will be processed as a formula, so `wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1) = cel.Text` should still cause problems.

Comment: @GSerg  See if **EDIT#1** behaves better.

Comment: That's exactly same code, the compiler will transform your first code to just that. Explicitly mentioning `Value` does not help, Excel will try to be smart with what you are assigning to it.

Comment: I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error" with the following highlighted. 

wk.Cells(cel.Row, 1).Value = s

Comment: @Gary's Student  your code works fine without error. Moves last column of the used range to column A